# text flow direction of a TextBox in c# 4.0

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Is there a way to change the text flow direction of a TextBox to `RightToLeft` instead of `LeftToRight` in c# 4.0. I know it can be done in WPF using `FlowDirection` Property. Is there something like that in Windows????

If not what way can this be achieved. Will I have to override the TextBox Class and if yes exactly which property I need to change.

Please point me to any link. I feel totally lost. Been researching for over a day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the TextBox's [RightToLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft.aspx) property to [RightToLeft.Yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.righttoleft.aspx)

```
myTextBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;
```

If you want your entire form and all ambient controls to inherit the `RightToLeft` property, you can set the Form's RightToLeft property to `RightToLeft.Yes`. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7d3337xw.aspx)

1. Set the form's RightToLeft property to Yes.
2. Set the form's RightToLeftLayout property to true.
3. Place a TextBox control on the form, either programmatically or
   using a development environment such as Visual Studio. It will
   inherit the right-to-left setting of the form, since the default
   value for the RightToLeft property is Inherit. (If you wish to
   override the setting for another control on the form, set that
   control's RightToLeft property to No.)
4. Compile and run your application. You will notice that the form's
   controls and title are mirrored to run from right to left. Enter
   text inside of the TextBox. You will notice that it enters from
   right to left.